# Node JS | Group Items on basis of name and Date Diff

Tags: javascript, node.js, group-by, lodash

**Problem Statement**

I am trying to group work experience on the basis of the company name which I am able to do. However, I want to group them only if they are consecutive jobs. The same logic LinkedIn has implemented.
I think a recursive way of grouping items based on name and date difference is needed.
for example

```
const data = [
    {
        Position: '1'
        CompanyName: 'Microsoft',
        StartDate: '2017-01-01',
        EndDate: '2017-04-01'
    },
    {
        Position: '2'
        CompanyName: 'Microsoft',
        StartDate: '2017-04-01',
        EndDate: '2017-10-01'
    },
        {
        Position: '3'
        CompanyName: 'Amazon',
        StartDate: '2017-10-01',
        EndDate: '2018-02-01'
    },
    {
        Position: '4'
        CompanyName: 'Microsoft',
        StartDate: '2018-03-04',
        EndDate: '2018-10-04'
    }
];
```

Currently, I am able to group by company name in node js using the following code

**Code**

```
/** applyGroupByPropName
* @param {Object} data this is the data object
* @param {string} propName This is the property to be grouped
* @returns {Object} returns a grouped object based on prop key
*/
    static applyGroupByPropName(data, propName) {
        if (!_.isNull(data) && !_.isEmpty(data) && data.length > 0) {
            data = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, propName),
                clist => clist.map(item => _.omit(item, propName)));
        }
        return data;
 }
```

and currently my output is like

```
   [ 
     CompanyName: 'Microsoft': [
     {
        Position: '1'   
        StartDate: '2017-01-01',
        EndDate: '2017-04-01'
    }, {
        Position: '2'
        StartDate: '2017-04-01',
        EndDate: '2017-10-01'
    }, {
        Position: '4'
        StartDate: '2018-03-04',
        EndDate: '2018-10-04'
    }
    ],
      CompanyName: 'Amazon' :
      [
        {
        Position: '3'
        StartDate: '2017-10-01',
        EndDate: '2018-02-01'
       }
      ]
   ]
```

**Expected Output**

```
   [ 
     CompanyName: 'Microsoft': [
     {
        Position: '1'   
        StartDate: '2017-01-01',
        EndDate: '2017-04-01'
    }, {
        Position: '2'
        StartDate: '2017-04-01',
        EndDate: '2017-10-01'
    }
    ],
      CompanyName: 'Amazon' :
      [
        {
        Position: '3'
        StartDate: '2017-10-01',
        EndDate: '2018-02-01'
       }
      ],
      CompanyName: 'Microsoft' :
      [
        {
        Position: '4'
        StartDate: '2018-03-04',
        EndDate: '2018-10-04'
       }
      ]
   ]
```

So Since position 4 is not the consecutive date it should not be grouped, Any ideas for this?
I don't want to group if the date difference is more than a month.

Comment: can you share your dummy array data, with expected output?

Comment: Done, I have updated with dummy data

Comment: Any other suggestions ?? looks interesting ?

Comment: The thing is your expected output is not a valid `array` or `object`. It should be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

In pure `JavaScript`, I'll go with `reduce` to do the task. Also let me know if this do the required task.

```js
var data = [ { Position: '1', CompanyName: 'Microsoft', StartDate: '2017-01-01', EndDate: '2017-04-01' }, { Position: '2', CompanyName: 'Microsoft', StartDate: '2017-04-01', EndDate: '2017-10-01' }, { Position: '3', CompanyName: 'Sapient', StartDate: '2017-10-01', EndDate: '2018-02-01' }, { Position: '4', CompanyName: 'Microsoft', StartDate: '2018-03-04', EndDate: '2018-10-04' }];

var result = 
data.reduce((acc,{CompanyName, ...rest})=>{
   acc[CompanyName] = acc[CompanyName] || [];
   if(acc[CompanyName].length>0){
     lastEndDt = acc[CompanyName][acc[CompanyName].length-1].EndDate;
     difference = Math.ceil(Math.abs(new Date(lastEndDt)- new Date(rest.StartDate))/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     if(difference<31){ acc[CompanyName].push(rest) } else { acc[`${CompanyName}_unordered`] =  [...(acc[`${CompanyName}_unordered`] || [] ), rest]};
     } else {
     acc[CompanyName].push(rest);
    }
  return acc;
},{});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: position 4 should come as a separate array

Comment: @TusharNarang I have updated my answer, have a look. What I did here is all unordered data for one company will go to separate array of that company.

Comment: Okay So will it be recursive, or will create 2 separate microsoft_unordered if it found 2 nonconsecutive dates.

Comment: @TusharNarang nope, it will merge in to the same. Let say if found more than 2 `Microsft` companies which are unordered it will move to the same key `Microsft_unordered`

Comment: Okay, then I will apply same logic to unordered ones right ?

Comment: @TusharNarang, definitely you can do that. so it will generated like  `Microsft_unordered_1`,`Microsft_unordered_2`...

Comment: I think what is needed is a recursive way of grouping it.